# How do I get a VBA function to acknowledge my Range object?

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, average

I'm trying to create a Range variable so that I can plug it into the [Average()] function.

But I keep getting a #NAME? error when I try to paste [Average(MyRange)] into a cell.

How can I properly create a Range variable so that the VBA Average function can calculate the values within the range?

Here is my code:

```
nextcol = 5
do until nextcol = 10
  Set myrange = mysheet.Range(mysheet.Cells(row, 3).Address & ":" & mysheet.Cells(row, nextcol).Address)
  mysheet.cells(row,nextcol) = [average(myrange)]
  nextcol = nextcol + 1
loop
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(mysheet.Range(mysheet.Cells(row, 3), mysheet.Cells(row, nextcol)))`.

Comment: Thank you GSerg, this is the answer